# How do I binary search a pandas dataframe for a combination of column values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Sorry if this is a simple question that the pandas documentation explains, but I've tried searching for how to do this and haven't had any luck.

I have a pandas datafame with several columns, and I want to be able to search for a particular row using binary search since my dataset is big and I'll be doing a lot of searches.

My data looks like this:

```
Name           Course   Week  Grade
-------------  -------  ----  -----
Homer Simpson  MATH001  1     97
Homer Simpson  MATH001  3     85
Homer Simpson  CSCI100  1     89
John McGuirk   MATH001  2     78
John McGuirk   CSCI100  1     100
John McGuirk   CSCI100  2     96
```

I want to be able to search my data quickly for a specific combination of name, course, and week.  Each distinct combination of name, course, and week will have either zero or one row in the dataset.  If there is a missing value for the combination of name, course, and week that I'm searching for, I want my search to return 0.

For instance, I would like to search for the value `(John McGuirk, CSCI100, 1)`

Is there a built in way to do this, or do I have to write my own binary search?

**Update:**

I tried doing this using the built-in way that was suggested by one of the commenters below, and I also tried doing it with a custom binary search that's written for my specific data, and another custom binary search that uses recursion to handle different columns than my specific example.

The data frame for these tests contains 10,000 rows.  I put the timings below.  Both binary searches performed better than using `[...]` to get rows.  I'm far from a Python expert, so I'm not sure how well optimized my code is.

```
# Load data
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import math
import pandas as pd
import time

file = 'grades.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file)

# This was suggested by one of the commenters below
def get_grade(name, course, week):
    mask = (df.name.values == name) & (df.course.values == course) & (df.week.values == week)
    row = df[mask]
    if row.empty == False:
        return row.grade.values[0]
    else:
        return 0

# Binary search that is specific to my particular data
def get_grade_binary_search(name, course, week):
    lower = 0
    upper = len(df.index) - 1

    while lower <= upper:
        mid = math.floor((lower + upper) / 2)

        row_name = df.iat[mid, 0]            
        if name < row_name:
            upper = mid - 1
        elif name > row_name:
            lower = mid + 1
        else:
            row_course = df.iat[mid, 1]
            if course < row_course:
                upper = mid - 1
            elif course > row_course:
                lower = mid + 1
            else:
                row_week = df.iat[mid, 2]
                if week < row_week:
                    upper = mid - 1
                elif week > row_week:
                    lower = mid + 1
                else:
                    return df.iat[mid, 3]

    return 0    

# General purpose binary search
def get_grade_binary_search_recursive(search_value):
    lower = 0
    upper = len(df.index) - 1

    while lower <= upper:
        mid = math.floor((lower + upper) / 2)

        comparison = compare(search_value, 0, mid)

        if comparison < 0:
            upper = mid - 1
        elif comparison > 0:
            lower = mid + 1
        else:
            return df.iat[mid, len(search_value)]

# Utility method
def compare(search_value, search_column_index, df_value_index):      
    if search_column_index >= len(search_value):
        return 0

    if search_value[search_column_index] < df.iat[df_value_index, search_column_index]:
        return -1
    elif search_value[search_column_index] > df.iat[df_value_index, search_column_index]:
        return 1
    else:
        return compare(search_value, search_column_index + 1, df_value_index)
```

Here are the timings.  I also printed the sum of the returned values from each search to verify that the same rows are getting returned.

```
# Non binary search
sum_of_grades = 0
start = time.time()   
for week in range(first_week, last_week + 1):
    for name in names:
        for course in courses:
            val = get_grade(name, course, week)
            sum_of_grades += val                
end = time.time()    
print('elapsed time: ', end - start)
print('sum of grades: ', sum_of_grades)
```

`elapsed time:  26.130020141601562`

`sum of grades:  498724`

```
# Binary search specific to this data
sum_of_grades = 0
start = time.time()    
for week in range(first_week, last_week + 1):
    for name in names:
        for course in courses:
            val = get_grade_binary_search(name, course, week)
            sum_of_grades += val

end = time.time()    
print('elapsed time: ', end - start)
print('sum of grades: ', sum_of_grades)
```

`elapsed time:  4.4506165981292725`

`sum of grades:  498724`

```
# Binary search with recursion
sum_of_grades = 0
start = time.time()
for week in range(first_week, last_week + 1):
    for name in names:
        for course in courses:
            val = get_grade_binary_search_recursive([name, course, week])
            sum_of_grades += val           
end = time.time()    
print('elapsed time: ', end - start)
print('sum_of_grades: ', sum_of_grades)
```

`elapsed time:  7.559535264968872`

`sum_of_grades:  498724`

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) , aso please post a desired output dataframe

Comment: Is there something wrong with using `numpy.where` or the `df[((df.Name == 'foo') & (df.Week == 'bar'))]` syntax?

Comment: What is your "specific combination" you want to search for, and like posted above. Include your data so we can copy and paste it.

Comment: @CumminUp07 From a functional standpoint there's nothing wrong with that, but does your example do a binary search?  I don't want to do a sequential search.

Comment: I don't know what kind of search it does but I know from experience that both are fairly quick.

Comment: Why is it so important for you to know if it's a binary search or not. These methods are optimized down to the `c code` and are really fast. This applies to almost all `pandas` / `numpy` methods, with the exception of some which are basically `for loops` on the background.

Comment: @Erfan The actual data will have millions of rows and I'll be doing millions of searches, so even a well optimized linear search isn't going to perform well.

Comment: If you want to dive into the technical background, `pandas` uses `boolean indexing`, see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I just ran a timing test selecting based on 4 columns on a dataframe with 5 million rows `64 ms ± 595 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: for performance check numpy search methods, edited to add the tag, also its advisable to add an example to demonstrate what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has [searchsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html).

From the **Notes**:

> Binary search is used to find the required insertion points.

Comment: The problem I had with that is that I don't know how to use it to insert into a dataframe that is sorted on several columns, rather than just the first column.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `my_dataframe.sort_values(by=['Name','Course','Week'], ascending=True)`

Comment: I've tried that, but it returns a `DataFrame` and `searchsorted` requires a `Series`